# Default assignment to a null variable with command substitution

Tags: bash, shell, string, command-substitution, variable-substitution

I'm trying to use the syntax:

```
A=${B:-C}
```

where `A` is the variable, `B` is the value I'm trying to assign, `C` is the default value if B is null.

Now I want to replace `B` with the command `nc -l 443`, so if `nc` receive a string through port 443, it is assigned to the variable `A`, else `A` is set to default value. I wrote the command as:

```
A=${`nc -l 443`:-NULL}
```

But I get an error:

```
-bash: A=${`nc -l 443`:-NULL}: bad substitution
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: syntax "A=${B:-C}" is **variable** expansion in bash but function. Firstly you  should assign result of function to variable, than use *variable expansion*

Answer (score 7):

Nested substitution is not available in any modern Bourne-like shells except `zsh`:

```
$ print -rl -- ${$(echo):-C}
C
$ print -rl -- ${$(echo 1):-C}
1
```

In other shells:

```
A=$(nc -l 443)
A=${A:-C}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, the line

```
A=${B:-C}
```

will assign the value of the variable `B` to the variable `A` if `B` is set and not null.  Otherwise the variable `A` will get the value `C`, i.e. the string containing the single character `C`.

What you might want to do:

```
B=$( some command )
A=${B:-C}
```

After this, `$A` will either be the output from `some command`, if it's not null, or the character `C`, if it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a variable in bash using command substitution, you can assign it to a default value when the command fails in the following way:

```
uid=$(id -u root || echo NULL)
echo $uid
uid=$(id -u nosuchuser || echo NULL)
echo $uid
```

If you prefer the backticks syntax:

```
uid=`id -u nosuchuser || echo NULL`
```

You can silence the error message by redirecting stderr to `/dev/null`:

```
uid=$(id -u nosuchuser 2>/dev/null || echo NULL)
```